# Asynchronous processing in java

Tags: java, concurrency

I am writing a Java API that needs to fetch data from some Web-Services asynchronously. The API needs to be portable having the ability to be used in regular Java SE, Java EE, Android, and BlackBerry applications, therefore I want to use some native Java API to accomplish this (for portability sake). I was thinking of using the Runnable interface to dispatch each request as a separate thread but I do not have a lot of experience with threads and I realize that you need to know what you are doing to pull it off properly.

What is the best way to accomplish this functionality asynchronously using Java?

Comment: What do you mean asynchronously?  [A simple google search led me to this](https://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/09/19/asynchronous-jax-ws-web-services.html)

Comment: If you decide to deal with this by getting to know what you are doing with threads, I recommend reading [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601).

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a `CachedThreadPool` or `FixedThreadPool` in `java.util.concurrent`. You'll want to use a `Callable` together with a `Future`, rather than `Runnable` because you want a value back from the web service call.

A very simple example:

```
public class MyAPI {
    public class SomeResponse {
        int value; // assumes some very basic service returns {"value":123}
    }
    // assumes spring 3+
    @Autowired RestTemplate restTemplate;

    ExecutorService pool = ExecutorService.newCachedThreadPool();

    Future<SomeResponse> getData(int someId) {
        return cachedThreadPool.submit(new Callable() {
            public SomeResponse call() {
                return restTemplate.getForObject("http://example.com/some/path/{someId}",SomeResponse.class, someId);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The caller of such a service can call `.get()` against the future to obtain the future result.

Answer (score 1):

Where is you asynchronous boundary?  In the code, or at the network?

If in the code, look into implementing (or exsiting implementations) of `java.util.concurrent.CompletionService`.  The `ExecutorCompletionService` will get you far along the way for many needs.

If in the network, you need to obtain an ID for the network request, and use that ID at some later time to obtain a response.  The actual implementation in code doesn't matter.

How will the response be accquired?  Will it be polled, or will it trigger a call back?

If it is polled, then have the requester check (possibly multiple times) for the result.  When it becomes available, then you have it.

If it is a call back, then add a interface (not the java keyword, the typical English usage) which the completion service can use without knowing the details of the object.  Have the requester contain (as part of the request) the information necessary to call the requester back with the results.

If polling, should the client block or busy wait?  Generally, blocking is preferred to save CPU resources, but busy waiting may be the logical choice when it is not possible to wake up the requesting `Thread` (perhaps due to it being on a different machine).  If you do busy wait, please do so responsibly.  Relinquish the CPU core by sleeping every second or so, it is extremely rare when the problem won't allow such a break, and without it, you will elevate electrical bills, cause unnecessary contention with other programs in the machine, and generally be a bad neighbor in the computer.

Comment: So you see, just like a decision between buying a house and a town home, you really have only scratched the surface.  You won't know which house you might buy until you decide on details like, how many rooms, what neighborhood, if you want more than on floor, etc.  Eventually, some of those answers will also affect the other answers, not every answer can be made independently.